# Consolidating a single row filling latest value from PCollection of CDC records using Apache Beam dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, cdc

Change data capture (CDC) records will not have all values for the columns in a record. It is possible that for a record's primary key, say R1 we can have PCollection of CDC records for R1 with CDC Timestamp. 
Ex. If Record R1 has columns C1, C2, C3, C4, CDCTimestamp

CDC records will be 
R1,C1.1,--,C3.1,--,10:02 
R1,C1.2,C2.2,--,C4.2,10:03 
R1,--,C2.3,--,C4.3,10:04 
R2,C2.1,--,C3.1,--,10:03

When Beam pipeline processes I need to get output as follows
PCollection containing
R1,C1.2,C2.3,C3.1,C4.3,10:04 
R2,C2.1,--,C3.1,--,10:03

Any pointers would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Is this batch or streaming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly.

What about

1) first transform it into KV pairs:

```
R1: C1.1,--,C3.1,--,10:02
R1: C1.2,C2.2,--,C4.2,10:03
R1: --,C2.3,--,C4.3,10:04
R2: C2.1,--,C3.1,--,10:03
```

2) Then do a GroupBykey:

```
R1-> C1.1,--,C3.1,--,10:02
     C1.2,C2.2,--,C4.2,10:03
     --,C2.3,--,C4.3,10:04
R2-> C2.1,--,C3.1,--,10:03
```

3) Then for each key, process the multiple elements and convert them into one.

Comment: It’s a batch processing. Each R is a CDC record that contains only updated columns of a base record where R1 is primary key.

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to Ruoyun Huang who pointed me in right direction... Attaching psuedo-code if any one else is interested in solving similar problem.

```
PCollection<TableRow> rowsFromBigQuery =
           pipeline.apply(
                BigQueryIO.readTableRows()
                    .fromQuery(QUERY)
                    .withoutValidation()
                    .usingStandardSql()
                   .withMethod(Method.DIRECT_READ));
                   //.withReadOptions(tableReadOptions));
// Seggregate by keys
PCollection<KV<String, TableRow>> rowByKeys =
            rowsFromBigQuery.apply("Seggregating by row keys", ParDo.of(new CreateKeyValue()));
// Group by keys
PCollection<KV<String, Iterable<TableRow>>> groupByKeys =
            rowByKeys.apply("Grouping by row keys", GroupByKey.<String, TableRow>create());
// Consolidate CDC
PCollection<TableRow> cdcConsolidatedRows =
            groupByKeys.apply("Consolidate CDC by row keys", ParDo.of(new ConsolidateCDC()));
```

Signatures for CreateKeyValue and ConsolidateCDC are as follows:

```
static class ConsolidateCDC extends DoFn <KV<String, Iterable<TableRow>>, TableRow> and static class CreateKeyValue extends DoFn<TableRow, KV<String, TableRow>>
```